# save parent child relationship with comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL 2008 R2

I have a table like below

```
| UID | Value | ParentID    |     Path
|:----|-------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1   |  A    |  NULL       |    |1|       |
| 2   |  B    |  1          |    |1|2|     |
| 3   |  C    |  2          |    |1|2|3|   |
| 4   |  D    |  1          |    |1|4|     |
| 5   |  E    |  NULL       |    |5|       |
```

While inserting the above first 3 columns, the fourth column Path should be able to save the relation with '|' separator. How this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bad idea to store data that is dependent on other records, worse idea to store collection data in a delimited string.  What are you trying to achieve?  What will `Path` be used for? (please add the answer to your question, not as a comment)

Comment: @DStanley For this type of structure, I'm actually a fan of using a HierarchyID column to store the full hierarchy in row (rather than materializing it on the fly every time through a recursive CTE).

Comment: @BenThul The risk is if one of the "parent" rows change you have to update all children recursively, otherwise your hierarchy data is out-of-sync.

Comment: Right. But you can put a trigger on the table (or do the update in a stored procedure that takes updating children into account) to do that if it's of concern to you. In my estimation, the pros (faster reads of the hierarchy) outweigh the cons (needing to maintain the hierarchy column).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As D Stanley mentions, you don't want to store the `Path` in your table. Better to just store the `UID`, `Value`, and `ParentID`, and then query the path data from that if and when you need it. If you need it often, you might consider defining a view on the table for that purpose. One way to perform the query is with a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Something like this should work:

```
-- Sample data from the question.
declare @x table ([UID] bigint, [Value] nchar(1), [ParentID] bigint);
insert @x values 
    (1, N'A', null),
    (2, N'B', 1),
    (3, N'C', 2),
    (4, N'D', 1),
    (5, N'E', null);

with [PathCTE] as
(
    -- Base case: any entry with no parent is its own path.
    select 
        *, 
        [Path] = convert(nvarchar(max), N'|' + convert(nvarchar, [UID]) + N'|')
    from
        @x
    where
        [ParentID] is null

    union all

    -- Recursive case: for any entry whose parent is already in the result set,
    -- we can construct the path by appending a single value to the parent path.
    select
        [Child].*,
        [Path] = convert(nvarchar(max), [Parent].[Path] + convert(nvarchar, [Child].[UID]) + N'|')
    from
        @x [Child]
        inner join [PathCTE] [Parent] on [Child].[ParentID] = [Parent].[UID]
)

select * from [PathCTE] order by [UID];
```